# Top align text vertically for training and main text in a ListTile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

For this ListTile the text is center aligned vertially. I would like to top align the text. What would be the best way to handle that? is it possible with a ListTile?

```
          child: ListTile(

            onTap: () {
              NavigationService.instance.navigateToReplacement(Transactions.route);
            },
            trailing: Text(NumberFormat.simpleCurrency().format(item.balance),
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: GlobalUI.listHeaderFontSize,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(item.name,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: GlobalUI.listHeaderFontSize,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              ),),
          ),
```

Comment: Can you attach screenshot what you want to make?

Comment: Maybe Row widget is better for your case

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap your Text widget around an Align widget

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  child: ...//your text widget
);
```

Comment: This did not work, when I added align the trailing text is center aligned across the row and the title text is gone.

Comment: Can you attach screenshot to the problem?